# Where to find information about patterns in 2D layout positioning and measurement?

Tags: design-patterns, layout

I would like to know the best practices/design patterns of layouting in 2D.

Must have reference to:

- absolute layout
- vertical layout
- horizontal layout

Components properties can be:

- width
- height
- minWidth
- minHeight
- maxWidth
- maxHeight
- top
- right
- bottom
- left
- x
- y
- horizontalAlign(left|center|right)
- verticalAlign(top|center|bottom)

---

Of course all these elements are not used for each component and are not used by all the layouts.

So for example I set a components width, height, top, right it should automatically recognize its bottom and left values.

Then about all these implication about minWidth, minHeight.

It can have a reference to how to find the scroller position, to appear when is needed.

*this will be build in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like java's swing. they use layout managers. gwt has a similar set of widgets and containers. microsoft has always had some of this similar, it's latest is wpf.

these frameworks use composite, iterator, flyweight, observer/observable (m$ has delegate which naict is an observable), and maybe strategy.

users of a framework could use mediator.